# How to show current location and button in the right corner?

Tags: android, location, maps, api-key

setMyLocationEnabled(true) used to work, but not anymore. I can't see what's missing in the code. The button at the top right corner and the blue dot for the position have both desapear

I have created new maps APIs, but not working

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }


        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);


    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;

        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(22));


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you make permission request before you set something to mMap?

Comment: Could you please explain me what you are saying here

Comment: In your code you make `checkSelfPermission`, and return in case that permissions not granted.  Where you request runtime permissions from user?